# Visual Studio 2022 - for typescript files Intellisense not working

Tags: typescript, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

I have a problem with the Intellisense on Typescript files in Visual Studio 2022 (on 2019 I didn't have this issue). From time to time the Intellisense stops working and the only solution I have is to exit from Visual Studio and reload the project. Is there any solution to force the the Visual Studio to reindex the files and hopefully the Intellisense will start working or are any other hidden settings that can help me to fix this annoying issue?

Comment: Same issue on my side.Its not working on my even after restart.I am using vs2019 with no issues

Comment: Same here: super-annoying, sometimes even the restart doesn't fix it. I suppose it's a memory issue, since it often happens when working with a lot of open TS files: however, I didn't find a way to reset such state.

Comment: Similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72276644/visual-studio-2022-typescript-intellisense-broken-in-17-2

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a large project that I copied over from an old machine on my new one. After searching around I found the answer. I found that the typescript types were not up to date so I firstly installed typesync by using the following command:

```
npm install -g typesync
```

Then in the clientapp folder I ran it (as it looks for the package.json file):

```
typesync
```

After restarting the project all was good!

For more info please see - https://github.com/jeffijoe/typesync

Comment: Tried that, did not help in my case but still good to know. There is typo in your command line which I can't fix because SO won't let you do edit of a single character.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - corrected the typo! If you manage to find another solution, I would be interest in it

Comment: For now I'll use Visual Studio Code until they fix it…

Answer (score 1):

please try the latest typescript version with the command:

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

Comment: Tried that and it did not help in my case as I was already using the latest version of TypeScript it seems. 4.6.4 at time of writing.

Answer (score 1):

We also faced similar issue when we opened projects in VS 2022. They were working fine previously in 2019. The fix was simple in our case.

Steps:

1. Added tsconfig.json file (we did not had this file in our project previously)
2. Then indicate the typeRoots path where you have the typedefinition files

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [ "/Scripts/typings" ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Now, clean the solution and rebuild. It worked for us. I hope it helps.

If anyone has a better solution, please advise.

Comment: I've tried it.... but it still doesn't work. Lately I think is something specific with Visual Studio 2022. I think it has to do with the background tasks.... that are never ending....

Comment: @DA what is the version of your VS 2022? If possible try updating to the newer version.

Comment: Mine is Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.2.6