# VS won't color my code, intellisense won't work, and go to definition and other functions won't work

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ide, visual-studio-2022

I can't provide any code because I'm under NDA, but as the title says, VS won't color my code or let me use any of the built-in tools it has. It allows me to rebuild and such, just not anything that directly edits or reveals any files. Google has absolutely nothing about the problem, everything is always VS Code. It's only for one specific project and it makes it very hard to work, does anyone know a solution? Has anyone ever heard of this problem?

It's Visual Studio 2022.

Edit:
The code is in TypeScript, with the `.ts` file extension, if that wasn't obvious, not to mention that it doesn't even interact with plain HTML. The only time it even colors the text is when I restart VS, then it goes back to not interacting with the text at all until I restart again, then it only highlights 2 of the files and stops again. This is the most information I could possibly give from my perspective, ask for any more you need.

Comment: I doubt the code is the issue - unless it is excluded by conditional compilation (and greyed-out).  The problem is more likely to be with the Intellisense set-up or project database. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982526/why-does-intellisense-and-code-suggestion-stop-working-when-visual-studio-is-ope but there are so many ways it can go wrong and many different solutions, it is unlikely you will get a definitive answer from just the info you provided.  Either way I found many similar discussions and numerous suggestions by Googling "_visual studio intellisense not working_"

Comment: ... what filename extension have you used?  What language are is this for?

Comment: @Clifford It's in TypeScript.

Comment: That was kind of a hint to fix the question rather than  add a comment.  You should probably tag it as such too.  Also you answered only one of my questions.  There is probably much information you can provide without contravening the NDA - I cannot see a definitive answer forthcoming from this scant information.

Answer (score 0):

I can usually fix this by simply closing VS and then reopening it.  It's definitely a glitch in Visual Studio with both Typescript and Javascript files.  If closing/reopening gets too annoying, there's some other things to try on this post:
[Visual Studio 2022 - for typescript files Intellisense not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70122013/visual-studio-2022-for-typescript-files-intellisense-not-working)