# Visual Studio 2022 TypeScript IntelliSense broken in 17.2

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2022

I have a couple of TypeScript projects where IntelliSense ain't working properly anymore. I suspect it could have been broken in 17.2 cause I did the version update yesterday. F12, to go to definition, mostly is not working anymore. If I search all references it finds a bunch of them but the actual class definition is classified as `Symbols without references`.
I updated TypeScript to 4.6.4 which is the latest version it seems but that still would not work.

[image: Symbols without references]

Some background tasks also never complete:

[image]

A collegue is still on 17.1 and it works for him.

Looks like it works on Visual Studio Code so I guess that will be my workaround for now.

Also got to try that same solution on another machine that is still running 17.1.4 and it works great there too. Very likely a regression introduced in 17.2.

Comment: Confirmed. You should send feedback to Microsoft (Help menu --> Send feedback --> Report a problem) so this bug can be fixed.

Comment: Will do, when I get a chance. Also kind of hopping someone in the Microsoft Visual Studio team is watching that SO tag. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: The issue was not fixed in 17.2.1.

Comment: Reported there: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/TypeScript-IntelliSense-broken-since-Vis/10051140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To workaround that issue you need to install ASP.NET. You could also wait until they release a fix. It was still not fixed in version 17.3.3.

See:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Go-To-Definition-lags-significantly-on-f/10051140#T-N10132388